# How to do "Login with Spotify" twice times for different purpose in the Laravel Application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am working on Laravel website.In that i have integrated functionality of "Login with spotify" and it is working fine.But in the website i have one more requirement is that i have to authenticate some users(login with spotify) which is created by admin.So it is possible to use same spotify developer application to do this thing or is there any other way because i have to mention another callback URL to get response from spotify.Already i have created one spotify developer application for "Login with spotify".

I have used Laravel Socialite "https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite" for "Login with spotify" in laravel.

Thanks in advance.